How to use cp's --update=none-fail option
I have cp (GNU coreutils) 9.5 on Arch Linux. The help seems to claim it has a --update=none-fail option, which will fail if a destination file already exists:
$ cp --help | grep '\--update\[=' -A1
  --update[=UPDATE]            control which existing files are updated;
                                 UPDATE={all,none,none-fail,older(default)}.

However, this doesn't seem to be an option when executing cp:
$ cp foo bar --update=none-fail
cp: invalid argument ‘none-fail’ for ‘--update’
Valid arguments are:
  - ‘all’
  - ‘none’
  - ‘older’


That was a bug in 9.5, fixed with (as yet unreleased):
https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/commit/de49e993e
